# Auth0 Additional properties not allowed: memberships

Tags: node.js, auth0, auth0-delegated-admin

I am using [Auth0 Delegated Administration Extension](https://github.com/auth0-extensions/auth0-delegated-administration-extension) to manage users. When I am trying to create user, I am getting this error.

> Oh snap! You got an error!
>
> An error occurred while creating the user:
>   {"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Payload validation
>   error: 'Additional properties not allowed: memberships (consider
>   storing them in app_metadata or user_metadata. See \"Users Metadata\"
>   in https://auth0.com/docs/api/v2/changes for more
>   details)'.","errorCode":"invalid_body"}

How could I solve this and create users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your create hook, try the following:

`return cb(null, {
  ...
  app_metadata: {
    memberships: memberships
  }
});`

You have to construct the object that is sent to the API. Some people want to store it in `app_metadata.groups` others in `app_metadata.departments` ...

Comment: Thanks. It worked. One last question. How can I assign roles to users via this extension?

Comment: Assigning roles to users is not supported yet in this extension. You can use the authorization extension, but this is not available for "end users" yet

Comment: Thanks for your support